# Modificar campos tabla Excel generado por Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, excel, kotlin

**Hola estoy intentando modificar los datos que genera un lector de código de barras que guarda los datos en formato Excel, Necesito reemplazar el campo isbn por la palabra codigo y date por fecha  como puedo hacer eso?**

**he intentado modificar esta parte pero da errores**

```
itemView.isbnTextView.text = "CODIGO: $isbn"
            itemView.dateTextView.text = date
```

---

```
 package com.awecode.thupraiisbnscanner.db.entity

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "barcodeData")
data class BarcodeData(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "isbn") var isbn: String,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "currency") var currency: String?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "price") var price: String?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: String,
                       @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB, name = "image") var image: ByteArray?)
```

**Adjunto fotos con el otro código porque Stackoverflow no me deja adjuntar mas código**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba cambiando esto: `@ColumnInfo(name = "codigo") var isbn: String` por esto: `@ColumnInfo(name = "codigo") var codigo: String` y para finalizar: `itemView.isbnTextView.text = "CODIGO: $codigo"` . Previo a esto recuerda limpiar los datos de la aplicación

Comment: ahora funciono muchas gracias!

Comment: bien, he añadido mi respuesta para que la marques como correcta así se cierra esta pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Bien, el error está en que la tabla tiene otro nombre por ende no lo encuentra. Prueba cambiar esto:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "isbn") var isbn: String
```

por esto:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "codigo") var codigo: String
```

Recuerda limpiar los datos de la aplicación